# Resize window (main frame) both horizontally and vertically in one time

Tags: java, swing

As you know in Java Swing you can re-size frames by dragging mouse, vertically, horizontally or both, but I like to do just a mouse drag for re-sizing both vertical and horizontal in one time and also this works when user move the mouse in all positions.  There is an example for what I want is solitaire game in windows, as you know in this game when user drags the mouse for re-sizing the window, the frame will be re-sized proportionately in both vertical and horizontal positions.

Is it possible for main frames (window) in Java Swing?

Comment: quite not possible on windows platforms, containers are based on peers came from native OS, then this properties aren't under Java control, sure must be an way to create an custom container, but you can't to pass it as peers for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for main frames (window) in Java Swing?

Not without some JNI/JNA.

Answer (score 0):

One hack is something like this. Use a `ComponentListener` and override its `componentResized()`. Every time the frame is resized, it will set the size to a relative width and height. Not sure if this is the desired effect you're looking for, but you can test it out.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

public class SampleFrame {
    public Dimension lastSize = new Dimension(400,300);

    public JFrame frame;
    public SampleFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("Sample Frame");
        frame.setSize(lastSize);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Dimension currentFrameSize = frame.getSize();
                int widthDelta = Math.abs(lastSize.width - currentFrameSize.width);
                int heightDelta = Math.abs(lastSize.height - currentFrameSize.height);

                if(heightDelta > widthDelta) {
                    double scaleRatio = currentFrameSize.getHeight() / lastSize.height;
                    currentFrameSize.width = (int) (lastSize.width * scaleRatio);
                } else {
                    double scaleRatio = currentFrameSize.getWidth() / lastSize.width;
                    currentFrameSize.height = (int) (lastSize.height * scaleRatio);
                }
                frame.setSize(currentFrameSize);
                lastSize = currentFrameSize;
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }

            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            }
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            }
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SampleFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, this code not works correctly, when drag the mouse, the frame not re-size correctly and also there is no stability on dragging.